# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'The' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in (FILE LOCATION) on line 17

Tags: php

I can't figure out what is wrong with my PHP code,  just started learning and I don't understand what is wrong. I keep getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'The' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in (FILE LOCATION) on line 17.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
// Set the variable number
$number = $_POST["number"];
if (!empty($number))
{
        if(!is_numeric($number))              
                        {
                             echo "The value you entered is not a number. Please enter a numerical                       
                              value”;

              }
              else
             {
             if($number < 10)
    { 
        echo "The number is smaller than 10";
    }
    else if ($number >= 10 && $number <=100 )
    {
        echo "The number is between 10 and 100";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "The number is larger 100";
    }
}
}
else
{
    echo "Please enter a number";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wrong quote character, take a look at syntax coloring...

Comment: @Usagi Miyamoto Where though?

Comment: Try putting `value”;` on the same line as your `echo`, or concatenating the two lines and echoing that out.

Comment: Additionally you have the wrong quote mark. It should be `value";`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line appears to be messing things up:

```
echo "The value you entered is not a number. Please enter a numerical                       
                          value”;
```

Instead, use:

```
echo "The value you entered is not a number. Please enter a numerical value";
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks a bunch!!!!!!!

Comment: Questions that are about basic PHP syntax errors should not be answered. They should be closed as a duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071) only.  See: [Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232). Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know what the actual problem was, you had a "smart quote" terminating your string.

The string was opened using a standard straight quote: `"`

but closing was attempting to be done by a curly quote: `”`

You can see in the syntax highlighting of your question that the string wasn't being terminated correctly.

I would also think your code editor, assuming it supports syntax highlighting (which, if it doesn't, you should change to one that does) would show the same thing.

Comment: Questions that are about basic PHP syntax errors should not be answered. They should be closed as a duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071) only.  See: [Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232). Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution anyway.